# QScrollArea save as image (jpg,tiff,png)

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

I have several "curves" ([something like this](http://www.qtcentre.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=8139&d=1345494542)) these curves are contained in a QVBoxLayout and this in turn is contained in a QScrollArea.

my question is, is there any way to keep these "curves" as an image file? ie jpg, png, tiff, etc..

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `QPixmap::grabWidget` to create a pixmap from a widget and save that.

Or `QWidget::render` to render the widget with a certain QPainter, which you can assign to a savable image